# import does not support the "as" attribute

Tags: java, ant, build

I am using Apache Ant to build something on a Ubuntu virtual machine.

When I do ant, and I got the following error:

```
Buidling failed:import does not support the "as" attribute
```

The version of java I have is 1.7, and for ant is also 1.7

Any clue? Millions of thanks!

Comment: Does it fail while executing an ant xml file ? Do you have the line ?

Comment: what ant task fails, what properties, be more specific!

Comment: Are you building in a IDE? Show the build.xml, please.

Comment: "Any clue?" Yes! Somewhere in your build script, or maybe in your source files, you'll find the word "import" and "as" close together. If you post the contents of file that meets that condition, perhaps someone will have another clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure javac is version 1.7 with `javac -version`, that's what is having a problem parsing the `as` keyword, not the java JVM application. The default in Ubuntu 12.10 is still 1.6, so you'd need to manually install a 1.7 JDK and then have it be the default by running `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. This [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) describes the different JVMs you can run in Ubuntu and how to select one.

Comment: Thanks thanks, the problem is actually the version of ant. I updated the ant version to 1.8 and then fix the problem. However, the other problem I have when I build is that:

Comment: JFCRipperMointor.java:288: isExpandable(edu.umd.cs.guitar.model.GComponent,edu.umd.cs.guitar.model.GWindow) in edu.umd.cs.guitar.ripper.JFCRipperMointor cannot override isExpandable(edu.umd.cs.guitar.model.GComponent,edu.umd.cs.guitar.model.GWindow) in edu.umd.cs.guitar.ripper.GRipperMonitor; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
    [javac]  boolean isExpandable(GComponent gComponent, GWindow window) {
    [javac]          ^

Comment: I thought it was the java or javac version problem, and then update both version to be 1.7..but this problem is still exist......BTW, the method itself is fine, I am just checking it out and using ant try to build it....

Comment: The problem is that (method isExpandable ?) is public in the base class, but in your subclass it doesn't have any access modifier so Java uses "package" access when none is specified. Prepend "public" to the method declaration and it should compile fine.